# programmatically Design a View in objective - C

Tags: ios, objective-c, programmatically-created

My project is design a View with numerous label, image, textField without storyboard or Nib. Do I need manually alloc and add every single thing to the view? I think this is very overkill but I have no idea how to do it any other way. Example:

```
UILabel *firstLabel =[UILabel alloc] init];
firstLabel.frame  = (0,x,20,10) ;
firstLabel.text = ...;
firstLabel.font = ...;
firstLabel.textColor = ...;
.................
[self.view addSubView:firstLabel];

UILabel *secondLabel =[UIlabel alloc] init];
secondLabel.frame = (0,y,20,10);    
secondLabel.text = ...;
secondLabel.font = ...;
secondLabel.textColor = ...;
.................
[self.view addSubView:secondLabel];

UILabel *thirdLabel =[UIlabel alloc] init];
    thirdLabel.frame = (0,z,20,10);    
    thirdLabel.text = ...;
    thirdLabel.font = ...;
   thirdLabel.textColor = ...;
    .................
    [self.view addSubView:thirdLabel];
```

Should I put all of them in `viewDidLoad` or `loadView` or `init` method?

Or I just need make a method for `CreatLabel` and use it again and again? How to do it?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly you ask how to apply DRY (Don't repeat yourself) to this code.

> «Two of more — use a for» <sub>Edsger W. Dijkstra</sub>

or

> «Two of more — use an enumeration» <sub>vikingosegundo</sub>

```
- (void)viewDidLoad { // or loadView, see Rob's answer
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSArray *properties= @[@{@"color": [UIColor orangeColor], @"text": @"Ceterum censeo"},
                          @{@"color": [UIColor cyanColor], @"text": @"Carthaginem esse"},
                          @{@"color": [UIColor purpleColor], @"text": @"delendam"}];

    [properties enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSDictionary *properties, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
          UILabel *l = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, (idx + 1) * 20, 200, 20)];
          l.backgroundColor = properties[@"color"];
          l.text = properties[@"text"];
          l.font= [UIFont italicSystemFontOfSize:12];
          [self.view addSubview:l];
      }];
}
```

Ok, why do I prefer this block-based enumeration here?
Because it has an mutation guard and gives me the correct index for free that I need for the frame.

A C `for`-loop `for (int idx = 0; idx < [properties count]; ++idx)` gives me the correct index but I must include an extra statement to get the object `NSDictionary *property = properties[idx];` and as it has no mutation guard: it could be changed during iteration which might lead to bad things.

A fast enumeration `for(NSDictionary *property in properties)` has such a mutation guard and is even slightly faster enumerating than the block  enumeration. But it has the big disadvantage that if I need the index, I must call `NSUIndex idx = [properties indexForObject:property];` causing a quadratic runtime performance instead of a linear: bye bye, speed advantage. And even worse: if an array contains identical objects it will only find the first one repeatedly — a good chance of creating false data.

Depending on the amount of the code, it might be useful to move this into a helper method — but this is more about taste.

---

As your question in the end is about readability, I want to share another matter of taste: I like to encapsulate object creation into a distinct scope:

Either by using an implicit block

```
UILabel *label = ^{
    UILabel *l =[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, (idx + 1) * 20, 200, 20)];
    l.backgroundColor = properties[@"color"];
    l.text = properties[@"text"];
    l.font= [UIFont italicSystemFontOfSize:12];
    return l;
}();
[self.view addSubview:label];
```

or a statement expression

```
UILabel *label = ({
    UILabel *l =[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, (idx + 1) * 20, 200, 20)];
    l.backgroundColor = properties[@"color"];
    l.text = properties[@"text"];
    l.font= [UIFont italicSystemFontOfSize:12];
    l;
});
[self.view addSubview:label];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're programmatically creating view from scratch, you'd do that in `loadView`. (See [Creating a View Programmatically](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ViewLoadingandUnloading/ViewLoadingandUnloading.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH10-SW36).) If, however, you have NIB/storyboard for the top level view and you are merely adding subviews, then you could do that in `viewDidLoad`.

Regarding the creation of a bunch of labels, yes, you could use subroutine. Or, assuming there is a regular pattern that dictates where these are positioned, you might even use a `for` loop in which you increment the `y` coordinate or build the constraints. (You can save references to these views in an array or use `tag` values to keep track of them.) But however you do it, yes, you'd want to minimize the amount of repeated code you write (simplifying life from a maintenance perspective, if nothing else).

Comment: Note that since the WWDC2015 Apple (finally!!!) discourages the usage of `tag` to keep track of views. see [Cocoa Touch Best Practices](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=231)

Answer (score 0):

It is okay to put in ViewDidLoad() but use custom method if there are large number of labels.